# unable to get the individual values from curl get call

Tags: shell, curl, jenkins

This it my Curl get command

```
Status=$(curl -X GET -H "ExecutionHistoryID: $guid" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  $uri/ExecutionStatus/)
```

The result is as follows:

> {"Status":"Running","ExecutionStatus":"Executing","Tasks":[{"Name":"ISMIMD_CNFReporting_DashBoard_EngReport","ExecutionStatus":"","ResourceName":"137.182.160.225","LastReportedError":"","Status":"Executing"}]}

Here how to get status inside the json result?
I need the output as Running or Executing to be printed

Comment: You will need to use a tool that is able to parse JSON.  For example, the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool.

Comment: This is written in Jenkins shell scripting. We need to get the status and pass or fail the Jenkins job. How can we parse in shell scripting?